# Ubuntu 20.04, wifi and dual monitor not working

Tags: wireless, 20.04, monitor

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was working fine after initial install. After the weekend I came back and neither my wifi nor second monitor working.

Have screenshots of video/network diagnostics below.

Seems I have unclaimed devices. Does anyone know how to install what's necessary without my wifi?

Appreciate your feedback!

[Video diagnostics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnxHA.jpg)
[Network diagnostics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aiz4V.jpg)

Wifi: Intel corp wireless-ac 9620. RTL8111 PCIE, Realtek Semiconductor.
Graphics:Radeon RX 5700 XT.Driver amdgpu-core version 20.20-1098277

Comment: By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals. to see your text. Rather, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the `{}` formatting tool.

Comment: thank you - unfortunately i dont have internet on my linux install. thats why i needed to take pictures. appreciate the tip!